# iOS - AFNetworking 2 Dispatch_once

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I've just updated Afnetworking 1 to 2.1 and app started to crash. there was no problem at AF 1.0. How can i solve this problem?

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[API initWithBaseURL:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa3e6810'

---

API.m

```
+ (API*)sharedInstance {
static API *sharedInstace = nil;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
sharedInstace = [[self alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kAPIHost]];
sharedInstace.securityPolicy = [AFSecurityPolicy policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModeNone];
});

return sharedInstace;
```

}

Comment: AFHTTPClient is self. its used on AF 1. but its removed at 2. i tried AFHTTPRequestOperation class but it didnt get any results.

Comment: `AFHTTPClient` is gone in 2.x. Try with `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`. http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.0/Classes/AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.html